# how to interpret content-length for XHR requests?

Tags: javascript, go, xmlhttprequest

I want to track progress for uploading a large file which I'm chunking on the client using XHR.
On my server, I take some data out of the form and persist N bytes to disk. What I'm confused about is that if I don't return the exact value that the client sent, it gets a content-length mismatch error. How does this make sense?

I send a form, with say 100 bytes and 80 of the bytes are the data I write to disk. Once I write the 80 bytes to disk, the server returns 80 for the content-length header. Why does the browser assume that I should write the same amount of bytes I sent?

Comment: `the server returns 80 for the content-length header` ... I thought you were talking about an UPLOAD ... not a DOWNLOAD - if your server responds with a content-length of 80, then it should send 80 bytes to the client

Comment: I'm uploading a file and writing it, then letting the client know I wrote N bytes from the upload to disk. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. I have it working right now by not returning a content-length at all and listening to xhr.upload.load event

Comment: if your server responds with a content-length header with a value of 80, then it should send 80 bytes to the client in the body - if you want to respond to the client that you wrote 80 bytes, do so in the response body - or make up your own header `x-bytes-written` for example